# Angular 2 get json data in div tag

Tags: html, json, angular

I'm New to Angular 2,working with json data, while processing with typescript, i get json data from the Object using `{{ data | json }}`,instead of JSON Variable i need to get the data in `<div>` tag on my web page.Is there any solution available ?

Ex: If the data is in the following format:

```
{ type:"header",subtype:"h1",name:"FormName" }
```

I need it in the following format:

```
<h1>Form Name</h1>
```

Comment: `<h1>{{data.name}}</h1>` ? Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: i think he needs to get that subtype in HTML tags and name inside it.

Comment: I have 10 different sets of json data from that i need to match them with relevent div with that data,the tags i use are text,number,date,header and etc.,

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question exactly, you could use innerHtml function in Angular2.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements {
constructor() {
}

data = { type:"header",subtype:"h1",name:"Formname" };
  htmlString=`<${this.data.subtype}>${this.data.name</${this.data.subtype}>`;}
```

app.component.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you retrieve entire form's content from a service as an array of objects, each one having a single element.
Iterate over the array using
**ngFor(obj of arr)

var element = '<{{obj.subtype}}>{{obj.value}}'

formElement.append(element)*

(this is just a stub to illustrate. This will create all types of elements, you just have to take care of different types of properties, like css)